# うまいclassの書き方

Tags: python, python3

やろうとしたことを満たすコードを書いたのですが、BaseNutritionクラスのメソッドnutrition_calculatorがなんとなく、汚い（冗長なコードのような気がする）のですが、もっときれいに書く方法はありますか？初心者で正直、関数、クラスの使い訳もうまくできないと思います。正直このようなコードをクラスで書くべきかどうかもわかりません。何がいいコードで何が悪いのかよくわからないので、見ていただきたいと思いました。改善できるところがありましたら教えていただけると嬉しいです。（あいまいな質問ですいません。）

やろうとしたこと。
まず、BaseNutritionクラスで食べ物の総量、総量グラムに対するタンパク質、炭水化物、脂質の属性を作った。
そして、BaseNutritionオブジェクトに栄養価の辞書データを与えることで、その食べ物を何グラムかを、nutrition_calculatorメソッドに渡すことによって、渡した重さに対する栄養価がわかるようなコードを書きました。

```
class BaseNutrition():

    def __init__(self, amount, kcal, carbohydrates, protein, fat):
        self.amount = amount
        self.kcal_per_gram = kcal / amount
        self.carbohydrates_per_gram = carbohydrates / amount
        self.protein_per_gram =  protein / amount
        self.fat_per_gram = fat / amount

    def nutrition_calculator(self, grams):
        kcal = round(grams * self.kcal_per_gram,1)
        carbs = round(grams * self.carbohydrates_per_gram,1)
        protein = round(grams * self.protein_per_gram, 1)
        fat = round(grams * self.fat_per_gram, 1)

        result_calculation = []
        result_calculation.append(kcal)
        result_calculation.append(carbs)
        result_calculation.append(protein)
        result_calculation.append(fat)

        return result_calculation

chiken_nutrition = {"kcal":116,
          "carbohydrates": 0,
          "protein": 19,
          "fat": 4 ,
          "amount": 100}

chiken = BaseNutrition(**chiken_nutrition)


print(chiken.nutrition_calculator(200)) # [232.0, 0.0, 38.0, 8.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そうですね、、、この場合、クラスではなく関数でも十分ではないかと思います。

```
def nutrition_calculator(base, amount):
  return [
    round(amount * val / base['amount'], 1)
    for attr, val in base.items() if attr != 'amount'
  ]

if __name__=='__main__':

  chiken_nutrition = {
    'kcal':          116,
    'carbohydrates':   0,
    'protein':        19,
    'fat':             4,
    'amount':        100,
  }

  print(nutrition_calculator(chiken_nutrition, 200))
```

とは言うものの、例えば `chiken_nutrition` に `amount` キーがない場合などのエラー処理がありませんし、出力結果が

```
[232.0, 0.0, 38.0, 8.0]
```

となっていて、それぞれの数値がどの属性に対応するのか判然としません(Python 3.6以降では辞書のキーの順序が挿入順になりますけれども)。

以下のコードでは、エラー処理を追加して、戻り値を dict 型のインスタンスにしています。参考にしてみて下さい。

```
import sys

class BaseNutrition(object):
  base_key = 'amount'

  def __init__(self, nutri):
    self.nutri = nutri

  def __enter__(self):
    try:
      self.amount = self.nutri[self.base_key]
      1 / self.amount
    except:
      self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
      return None

    return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    if exc_type is None:
      return
    elif exc_type == KeyError:
      print(f"`{self.base_key}' is not found.")
    elif exc_type == TypeError:
      print(f"`{self.base_key}' is not a number.")
    elif exc_type == ZeroDivisionError:
      print(f"`{self.base_key}' is zero.")
    else:
      print(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)

  def calculator(self, amount):
    return {
      attr:
        amount if attr == self.base_key
               else round(amount * val / self.amount, 1)
      for attr, val in self.nutri.items()
    }

if __name__=='__main__':

  chiken_nutrition = {
    'kcal':          116,
    'carbohydrates':   0,
    'protein':        19,
    'fat':             4,
    'amount':        100,
  }

  with BaseNutrition(chiken_nutrition) as chiken:
    if chiken is not None:
      print(chiken.calculator(amount=200))
      print(chiken.calculator(amount=50))

=>
{'kcal': 232.0, 'carbohydrates': 0.0, 'protein': 38.0, 'fat': 8.0, 'amount': 200}
{'kcal': 58.0, 'carbohydrates': 0.0, 'protein': 9.5, 'fat': 2.0, 'amount': 50}
```